# How to save visible column state in bootstrap table toolbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table toolbar in my table list. Now while uncheck any column from toolbar it's hide that column from table heading,but now how i will save this visible column states to see after refreshing the page?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 'Table Cookie' extension. It saves:

- Sort order
- Page number
- Page number from the list
- Visible columns
- Search text

Source: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/cookie

Example: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/

Include the JS file

```
<script src="extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.js"></script>
```

and add this attributes to your table:

```
data-state-save="true",
data-state-save-id-table="whateverIdYouLike"
```

Cookies must be enabled to use this extension.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the data attributes have been updated since @Martin's post, however the two fields:

```
data-state-save="true",
data-state-save-id-table="whateverIdYouLike"
```

are not being used. Per current example: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/

View with debug tool:

Just utilize data-cookie-id-table instead and ensure it's value is unique if using multiple bootstrap tables on site.

Answer (score 0):

Full source example [here](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/cookie.html#view-source).

```html
<link href="bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" 
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-cookie="true"
  data-cookie-id-table="saveId"
  data-search="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  })
</script>
```

Otherwise

```html
<link href="bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        showColumns   : true,
        cookie        : true,
        cookieIdTable : "saveId",
        search        : true
    })
  })
</script>
```